# How to handle dynamic urls with vue and search engines

Tags: vue.js

I have a conceptual problem with a vuejs application. Project pages are generated from a json file via router, the URL then looks like this.

domain/project/projectnumber/projectname

If I now insert a new project into the Json file above, the project number and project name assignment will of course shift every time. Overall then there is a problem with search engines.

OK, I could sort it inversely, then the project number and project name always remain identical, but as soon as a project is removed, there is of course a problem again.

how do you proceed here? I could of course check in the router via beforeEach whether the route is available under a new ProjectID. but is that the usual way? Or am I missing something here.

Comment: "If I now insert a new project into the Json file above" - you didn't show the file, it's unclear where you insert it and why it shifts. Data entry is supposed to have unique id if you need refer it somehow. Databases commonly have autoincrement ids. If you need an id then explicitly use it. It's unclear why numeric id is necessary, it could be name field, etc. If you still need numeric id and need entries to keep their ids regardless of the changes in an array, then write ids explicitly

Comment: Every few weeks a new project simply comes into the Json. I understand your objection, so far the project ID has been passed on from the project list to the project details page via router. If only the project name is passed on, but the ID is stored in the store, for example, the URL looks fine. When calling up a url from an external page, it would only have to be checked whether this url exists and, if so, the project ID should be determined.

Comment: Do you mean that /project/projectname currently redirects to /project/projectnumber/projectname ? It would make sense to make /project/projectname canonical instead and don't use numeric ids at all because they are flaky in your case

Comment: OK, so far it works perfectly without ID. but now when I come from an external site, router.beforeEach is called before my json file is loaded. Of course I would like to check whether the project page URL called up exists. Or do I just determine in beforeeach that the site was accessed externally and then check the URL after everything has loaded?

Comment: "router.beforeEach is called before my json file is loaded" - this is probably the problem here, router hooks are a good place to fetch data that a route relies on to avoid race conditions. If you don't want to change that for some reason then likely yes, you can redirect to 404 or canonical url any time you find out that  route url mismatches your expectations

Comment: That's how I do it now, I determine whether there is an external call from a project or another page, load everything, then if necessary I call up an adapted URL. Thanks!